# Not able to install docker-machine in Centos 7

Tags: bash, docker, centos7, docker-machine, docker-swarm

Docker is installed in my Centos 7 machine:

```
Client: Version:      17.03.1-ce API version:  1.27
Server:  Version:      17.03.1-ce  API version:  1.27 (minimum version 1.12)
```

But I am not able to install docker-machine. Below is how I try to install it:

```
wget https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.6.0/docker-machine-$(uname
-s)-$(uname -m)
mv docker-machine-Linux-x86_64 docker-machine
chmod +x docker-machine
sudo mv docker-machine /usr/local/bin
```

And when I check for the docker-machine version,

```
docker-machine version
```

I get below error:

```
bash: docker-machine: command not found...
```

Answer (score 4):

Move to `/usr/bin instead` of `/usr/local/bin`

```
mv docker-machine /usr/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the docker-machine to your path as shown here:
[Docker Installing bash completion](https://docs.docker.com/machine/install-machine/#installing-bash-completion-scripts)

If not are you able to run `/usr/local/bin/docker-machine version`

Any errors and full output would be appreciated!

Comment: No, I am not able to run this either: /usr/local/bin/docker-machine version

Answer (score 0):

I have followed your steps, that is:

```
wget https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.6.0/docker-
machine-$(uname-s)-$(uname
-m) mv docker-machine-Linux-x86_64 docker-machine chmod +x docker-machine
```

but at this point instead I wrote:

```
sudo cp docker-machine /usr/local/bin
docker-machine version
docker-machine version 0.6.0, build e27fb87
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with @Tioma, doing the first step and it works perfectly

[Install docker machine on Centos 7](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-provision-and-manage-remote-docker-hosts-with-docker-machine-on-centos-7)

> [root@osboxes Desktop]# mv docker-machine-Linux-x86_64 docker-machine
>
> [root@osboxes Desktop]# chmod +x docker-machine
>
> [root@osboxes Desktop]# sudo mv docker-machine /usr/bin
>
> [root@osboxes Desktop]# docker-machine version
>
> docker-machine version 0.6.0, build e27fb87

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following steps:

- Manually download package from https://archlinux.pkgs.org/rolling/archlinux-community-x86_64/docker-machine-0.16.1-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz.html
- Unpack the file
- Move docker-engine file to usr/bin
- Run following `chmod +x docker-machine`
- `docker-machine version` to test if install works.

Answer (score 0):

Create symbolic link 
`sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/docker-machine /usr/bin/docker-machine`